# I'm unable to import JSON file via azure PowerShell

Tags: json, azure, powershell

I've created a JSON file for custom RBAC definition, file are import but not used by FileInput command in azure powershell.

I've run the below mentioned command in azure powershell

```
New-AzRoleDefinition -InputFile $HOME/muhammad/rbac.json
```

I've the error mentioned below.

> New-AzRoleDefinition: File /home/muhammad/muhammad/rbac.json does not
> exist

I want to import my custom JSON but I'm unable

Comment: Maybe `$HOME/rbac.json` could work?

Comment: to find the right path, use 'pwd' command from the folder where the 'rbac.json' file exists.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results.

When I try the same command in my environment got the same error.

[image]

I have followed the below steps to solve this issue.

To list the available assignment scopes:

```
Get-AzRoleDefinition | FT Name, IsCustom
```

By using the below command it will list the custom roles that are available in the selected subscription:

```
Get-AzRoleDefinition -Custom | FT Name, IsCustom
```

Created the custom role with rile definition object using json template.

I have created the json file and added the roles
`vi rabc.json`

To add the role to the subscription I have used the below command:

```
New-AzRoleDefinition -InputFile  "$homs/komali/rabc.json"
```

[image]